# Yii GACounter extension error: Call to undefined method GACounter::init()

Tags: php, yii

I'm working on an extension for my site that's a wrapper class for this [google analytics php class](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/). **I'm not extending any of the Yii classes**.

i put this class in `extensions/GACounter/GACounter.php`

```
class GACounter
{
    public $ga_email;
    public $ga_password;
    public $ga_profile_id;

    public function __construct($arr = array())
    {
        $this->ga_email = Yii::app()->params['ga_email'];
        $this->ga_password = Yii::app()->params['ga_password'];
        $profileId = Yii::app()->params['ga_profile_id'];
        self::setProfile($profileId);

        if (!empty($arr)) {
            foreach($arr AS $k => $v) {
                $this->$k = $v;
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception('Array is empty, no settings passed.');
        }
    }

    .....
}
```

when i call this class in my view, like this

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.GACounter.GACounter');

$ga = new ExtGoogleAnalyticsCounter(
            array(
                'customDateChart' => true,
                'startDate' => $startDate,
                'endDate' => $endDate,
                'dimensions'=> $dimensions,
                'metrics'=>urlencode('pageviews'),
                'sort_metric'=>$sort_metric,
                'filter'=>'pagePath=='.$url,
                'start_index'=>1,
                'max_results'=>abs($dateRange)
                ) 
         );

$totalSiteTraffic = $ga->GetTotalTraffic();

$chartData = $ga->GetChartPerDay();
```

i get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method GACounter::init() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev/common/lib/yii/framework/web/CBaseController.php on line 147
```

**only when i add this 2 functions in my class**, do i not get the error above

```
public function init() { }
public function run() { }
```

any idea why this is so? I'm using Yii 1.1.16

Comment: If you are developing widget, you should extend from `CWidget`, ie.: `class GACounter extends CWidget`.

Comment: @PeterM still kind of new to Yii. but can i set a wiget to a variable and echo it later? or call a specific function in the widget? like how i did `$totalSiteTraffic = $ga->GetTotalTraffic();` ?

Comment: It depends on how you call it. If you simpy use `new Class...`, you can use it as any object. However calling `$this->widget('path.to.widget')` will call `CWidget` methods, for instance `init` and `run`.